# Associate result of TPL dataflow pipeline with initial post

Tags: c#, http, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm working on creating a dataflow pipeline that is responsible for asynchronously processing HttpRequests sent to an `HttpListener`. In order to respond to the request, I might have to do some time consuming operations such as analyzing or pulling large amounts of data from a database, thus the dataflow approach. I'm using the `HttpListener.GetContextAsync` to pass the `HttpListenerContext` into the first block in the pipeline, which will then process the request and generate a response.

The problem that I'm running into is that I need to have the original `HttpListenerContext` object in order to send a response back to the client. My first thought was that I could just pass the object through the whole pipeline inside of a Tuple but that quickly starts to look and feel really messy.

Ultimately, from a design standpoint I'd like to be able to pass in the `HttpListenerContext` to the pipeline and at the end of the process receive a response that I can then issue back without needing to pass the object through the whole thing as well. Is it possible to associate the end result of the pipeline back to the initial object that was posted into it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a TPL Dataflow block downstream get data produced by a source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612468/how-can-a-tpl-dataflow-block-downstream-get-data-produced-by-a-source)

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612468/how-can-a-tpl-dataflow-block-downstream-get-data-produced-by-a-source/31482290#31482290

Comment: Are you creating the pipeline for each request?